# Struts2 FTL Tags with Map

Tags: freemarker

Iam developing a web application with free marker template using Struts2 tag libs.
I have a map in the request object with attribute name as "namesToBeUsed"

How to assign it to a variable in ftl using struts2 tag?

Iam getting below error if I assign like this  <@sftl.set name="namesToBeUsed" value='${Request["namesToBeUsed"]}'/>

Expecting a string, date or number here, Expression Request["namesToBeUsed"] is instead a freemarker.template.SimpleHash

Can any one help me? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

```
<@sftl.set name="namesToBeUsed" value=Request["namesToBeUsed"] />
```

because `'${whateverExpression}'` does string interpolation, and hence had to convert the expression value to string. So inside FreeMarker tags, just enter the expressions without any extra syntax around them.